# Use case of AWS lambda to nodejs project on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a thumbnailing function running on lambda, and I want to deploy it on elastic beanstalk. Lambda did a lot of background jobs for me so that when I deploy my function to elastic beanstalk, it won't work for me properly as I expected.

My lambda function can thumbnail all images in a given folder of given s3 bucket, and store them into different size images in the same location when it's triggered. However, when I deployed that to beanstalk, it will not be triggered by any of s3 events.

I know the rough step to fix it, but I need to know few specific things:

1. Before creating a lambda function, we need to configure event resourses:
   [image]
   [image]

I want to know if I can somehow pass them in beanstalk, I'm thinking about passing a json into my node.js function, but I don't know exactly how.

2. I don't know if I should add my function in an infinite loop to monitor events notifications from s3.
3. I want to combine this node.js function with other independent node.js service by express. And I want to display summary message about how many images has been thumbnailed in browser. But currently, with lambda package structure, I'm exporting a function handler to other js files. How can I export internal data to another static hjs/jade page?
4. How can I get the notification from s3?

In brief, if it isn't worthy of adding such complexity to deploy lambda function to beanstalk, should I just leave it as a lambda function?

Comment: You need to store "internal data" somewhere other than Lambda or Elastic Beanstalk. I recommend using DymamoDB or possibly ElastiCache (Redis) to store the data you want to summarize and display. Then you can have Lambda functions and/or any number of Elastic Beanstalk servers updating that data while making it available to your web app.

Comment: Then that's way more work for me to manage a simple service. My current idea deploy any other micro services together on EB, and keep thumbnailer running as a lambda function.

Comment: @MarkB I doubt the scalability of lambda, but I do not know how I can get and send notifications to S3 to some service in EB. I don't want to change my structure a lot, because I only need to display the instant summary data once the function get triggered.

Comment: You doubt the scalability of Lambda? Perhaps you need to post details about that. I doubt the ability of a few EC2 instances managed by Beanstalk to handle as many concurrent image processing tasks as Lambda can. Regarding sending S3 notifications to EB, you would need to configure S3 to send notifications to an SNS topic, and configure the SNS topic to send notifications to an HTTP endpoint, and configure an HTTP endpoint in your EB application to receive and process those notifications.

Comment: @MarkB Your comment clearly explained what the potential work could be. I think my current approach is on the right track then. I wonder if you want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Elastic Beanstalk vs. AWS Lambda, I think Lambda is going to be more scalable, as well as cheaper, for this sort of task. And I think saving status information to a DynamoDB table would be a quick and easy way to make statistics available that you can display in your web application, while preventing those statistics from disappearing if you redeploy or restart your application. Saving that data in DynamoDB would also allow you to have more than one EC2 instance serving your website in Elastic Beanstalk without having to worry about synchronizing that data across servers somehow.

---

Regarding sending S3 notifications to Elastic Beanstalk, you would need to do the following:

1. Configure S3 to send notifications to an SNS topic
2. Configure the SNS topic to send notifications to an HTTP endpoint
3. Configure an HTTP endpoint in your Beanstalk application to receive and process those notifications